# Postgres Query Planner expects 1 row for a join doing a Nested Loop Join

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-planner

I'm having a performance issue when joining between 2 tables because the query planner estimates 1 row, instead of potentially thousands, and chooses to do a nested join. Some background on the query:

On Version 15.3

Two tables:

```
An items table:
id | company_id | name | ...

A linking table:
id | parent_item_id | child_item_id | link_type | company_id | ...
```

The query (A simplified version of the query):

```
Select ... from Items i
Join Links l on i.id = l.parent_item_id and l.link_type = 'foo'
join Items i_child on l.child_item_id = i_child.id
....
where ....
```

The items table has millions of records, and each item can have hundreds of links to other items through the links table.

The issue seems to be that the query planner expects there to be a single row per item -> child join, but in reality a parent item can link to many child items.

Here's an image of what the query planner is showing.

[image]

Questions:

1. Is there a way to force the query planner to have a better row estimate, or force it to try a hash join instead of a nested join? I've tried just to test `SET LOCAL enable_nestloop = False;` and it still chooses a nested join.
2. Is there a way to write a query like that in a different way that would be more performant?

Comment: Have you tried [analyzing your tables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-analyze.html) to ensure the query planner is using up to date statistics?

Comment: I did, it didn't have any affect on the performance

Comment: Please show a complete plan in a text format, not a mutilated one in an image format.  Whatever is going on here is in the part of the plan which has been cropped away.

Comment: @jjanes The query plan is to long to include in the stack overflow question, is there a suggested way to share those?

Comment: I prefer https://explain.depesz.com/

Comment: @jjanes Thanks! Here's a link https://explain.depesz.com/s/hXgB#html.

Comment: It is not clear to me what better plan would be chosen if the row estimate were accurate.  I suspect that is not the problem. But there is a mystery here in that one nested loop takes far more time than either of its children, and that is most of the time of the plan.  I'm guessing that some computation done at that node is very slow.  EXPLAIN VERBOSE should show the output of each node, and maybe that would give us a clue as to what the problem is.